# Outlook addin: 'window.open(url)' works but returns null

Tags: null, outlook-web-addins, window.open

I have an Outlook addin with 2 options: 1 buttons for an action + 1 button for a task pane

**In the task pane code** (.js file), I open a window and get the reference, to close it when required:

`var myWindow = window.open(sUrl,...)`  // myWindow is valid and the dialog is open properly

**In the action code** (.js file), if I use the same code, myWindow is null. However, the dialog is open properly displaying sUrl page)

What can be the difference? How can I get the window object in the 2nd case, to close it?

---

**EDIT:** (responses for a comment answers)

1. I have tested in Chrome & in Edge browsers: in both I receive a null
2. It happens always for me
3. I have a function like that:

   ```
         function openDialog(sUrl) {
            var w = 800;
            var h = 500;
            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
            var dialog = window.open(sUrl, "window1", 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',scrollbars=NO, top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            console.log("Dialog: " + dialog);
        }
   ```

The dialog is always displayed and running properly, but:

- When I call it from a taskpane (button), in the JS code 'dialog' has a valid value
- When I call it from an action (Office.onReady() method in JS file), 'dialog' is null

---

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: Is using displayDialogAsync API instead an option?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Comment: I tried to do that, but I receive an error in the dialogCallback 
  12004 (Domain not trusted)

The URL is the same than works with 'window.open()' (popup dialog is displayed in that case)

The URL is 'https://myserver.net/auth/...'

In my addin manifest I have:
    <AppDomain>myserver.net</AppDomain>

Comment: Is the the domain the same domain as the host page (including protocol and port number)?

Comment: The html page i open in the popup is in a different server than the html page of the action, from which js code i launch the window. That is why i thought about 'window.open' (2nd page is open in the window), but returns null object...

Comment: What is your Outlook version number? Instructions can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-version-of-outlook-do-i-have-b3a9568c-edb5-42b9-9825-d48d82b2257c).

Comment: I am using to develop Outlook Web 365

Comment: We are not able to repro bug at our end. Please answer few questions to help us debug better -
> 1. Is the issue browser specific or happens everywhere irrespective of browsers ?if so please specify browser + OS combination.
> 2. Does it happen every-time or it happens sometimes ?
> 3. Can you share code snippet, how you're doing it or a video to understand better.

Comment: I edited my post to response your questions. Thanks

Comment: Hello, we tried this at our end with the above code snippet. But we are still unable to repro this issue. Can you please hare the manifest file with us?

Comment: Thanks for your response, shall I paste all my manifest file text in a response (too long for a comment)? Or shall I send the file to you somehow?

Comment: As confirmed by @Diego the issue does not repro. It might have been an intermittent issue that was addressed by a subsequent bug fix.

Comment: Where did he confirm this? I am having this same issue now in the desktop client. When we do window.open, instead of returning a handle to the opened window, it returns null. The window still opens, but we are unable to get a reference to it.